# Get a list of photo albums from Facebook

Tags: php, facebook

I want to get list of photo albums. I used the following code but no luck.

```
$user = $facebook->getUser();
        $albums_str = "Here goes: ";
        if ($user) {
            try {

                $albums = $facebook->api('/me/albums');

                foreach ($albums['data'] as $album) {

                    $cover = "https://graph.facebook.com/{$album['id']}/picture? type=album&access_token={$facebook->getAccessToken()}";

                    // echo $album['name'];

                    $albums_str .= $album['name'];
                    // echo "<img src='https://graph.facebook.com/cover_photo/picture?type=normal'/>";
                }
            } catch (FacebookApiException $e) {
                error_log($e);
                $user = null;
                $albums_str .= '--Errorr--';
            }
```

Do I need to append some photo access code in the authentication url parameter?

Comment: For album cover look https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v2.7/album/picture

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to [Album documentation](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/album/) you need `user_photos` permission. So you should ask for that when authenticating new users.

P.S. Also please add if you got any errors from Facebook, maybe permissions is not the cause of your problem.

Comment: Thank you a lot. This is what I was missing.